# How to replace text URLs and exclude URLs in HTML tags?

Tags: php, html, regex, url

I need you help here.

I want to turn this:

```
sometext sometext http://www.somedomain.com/index.html sometext sometext
```

into:

```
sometext sometext <a href="http://somedoamai.com/index.html">www.somedomain.com/index.html</a> sometext sometext
```

I have managed it by using this regex:

```
preg_replace("#((http|https|ftp)://(\S*?\.\S*?))(\s|\;|\)|\]|\[|\{|\}|,|\"|'|:|\<|$|\.\s)#ie", "'<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$1</a>$4'", $text);
```

The problem is it’s also replacing the `img` URL, for example:

```
sometext sometext <img src="http//domain.com/image.jpg"> sometext sometext
```

is turned into:

```
sometext sometext <img src="<a href="http//domain.com/image.jpg">domain.com/image.jpg</a>"> sometext sometext
```

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege)

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 9):

Streamlined version of Gumbo's above:

```
$html = <<< HTML
<html>
<body>
<p>
    This is a text with a <a href="http://example.com/1">link</a>
    and another <a href="http://example.com/2">http://example.com/2</a>
    and also another http://example.com with the latter being the
    only one that should be replaced. There is also images in this
    text, like <img src="http://example.com/foo"/> but these should
    not be replaced either. In fact, only URLs in text that is no
    a descendant of an anchor element should be converted to a link.
</p>
</body>
</html>
HTML;
```

Let's use an XPath that only fetches those elements that actually are textnodes containing http:// or https:// or ftp:// and that are not themselves textnodes of anchor elements.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$texts = $xPath->query(
    '/html/body//text()[
        not(ancestor::a) and (
        contains(.,"http://") or
        contains(.,"https://") or
        contains(.,"ftp://") )]'
);
```

The XPath above will give us a TextNode with the following data:

```
 and also another http://example.com with the latter being the
    only one that should be replaced. There is also images in this
    text, like
```

Since PHP5.3 we could also [use PHP inside the XPath](http://cowburn.info/2009/10/23/php-funcs-xpath/) to use the Regex pattern to select our nodes instead of the three calls to contains.

Instead of splitting the textnodes apart in the standards compliant way, we will use a [document fragment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocumentfragment.php) and just replace the entire textnode with the fragment. Non-standard in this case only means, [the method we will be using for this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocumentfragment.appendxml.php), is not part of the [W3C specification of the DOM API](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core).

```
foreach ($texts as $text) {
    $fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
    $fragment->appendXML(
        preg_replace(
            "~((?:http|https|ftp)://(?:\S*?\.\S*?))(?=\s|\;|\)|\]|\[|\{|\}|,|\"|'|:|\<|$|\.\s)~i",
            '<a href="$1">$1</a>',
            $text->data
        )
    );
    $text->parentNode->replaceChild($fragment, $text);
}
echo $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);
```

and this will then output:

```
<html><body>
<p>
    This is a text with a <a href="http://example.com/1">link</a>
    and another <a href="http://example.com/2">http://example.com/2</a>
    and also another <a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a> with the latter being the
    only one that should be replaced. There is also images in this
    text, like <img src="http://example.com/foo"/> but these should
    not be replaced either. In fact, only URLs in text that is no
    a descendant of an anchor element should be converted to a link.
</p>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn’t do that with regular expressions – at least not regular expressions only. Use a proper HTML DOM parser like the one of [PHP’s DOM library](http://php.net/dom) instead. You then can iterate the nodes, check if it’s a text node and do the regular expression search and replace the text node appropriately.

Something like this should do it:

```
$pattern = "~((?:http|https|ftp)://(?:\S*?\.\S*?))(?=\s|\;|\)|\]|\[|\{|\}|,|\"|'|:|\<|$|\.\s)~i";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);
// for every element in the document
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('*') as $elem) {
    // for every child node in each element
    foreach ($elem->childNodes as $node) {
        if ($node->nodeType === XML_TEXT_NODE) {
            // split the text content to get an array of 1+2*n elements for n URLs in it
            $parts = preg_split($pattern, $node->nodeValue, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
            $n = count($parts);
            if ($n > 1) {
                $parentNode = $node->parentNode;
                // insert for each pair of non-URL/URL parts one DOMText and DOMElement node before the original DOMText node
                for ($i=1; $i<$n; $i+=2) {
                    $a = $doc->createElement('a');
                    $a->setAttribute('href', $parts[$i]);
                    $a->setAttribute('target', '_blank');
                    $a->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($parts[$i]));
                    $parentNode->insertBefore($doc->createTextNode($parts[$i-1]), $node);
                    $parentNode->insertBefore($a, $node);
                }
                // insert the last part before the original DOMText node
                $parentNode->insertBefore($doc->createTextNode($parts[$i-1]), $node);
                // remove the original DOMText node
                $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, since the [*DOMNodeList*‍s](http://php.net/domnodelist) of [`getElementsByTagName`](http://php.net/domdocument.getelementsbytagname) and [`childNodes`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.childnodes) are [live](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#td-live), every change in the DOM is reflected to that list and thus you cannot use `foreach` that would also iterate the newly added nodes. Instead, you need to use `for` loops instead and keep track of the elements added to increase the index pointers and at best pre-calculated array boundaries appropriately.

But since that is quite difficult in such a somehow complex algorithm (you would need one index pointer and array boundary for each of the three `for` loops), using a recursive algorithm is more convenient:

```
function mapOntoTextNodes(DOMNode $node, $callback) {
    if ($node->nodeType === XML_TEXT_NODE) {
        return $callback($node);
    }
    for ($i=0, $n=count($node->childNodes); $i<$n; ++$i) {
        $nodesChanged = 0;
        switch ($node->childNodes->item($i)->nodeType) {
            case XML_ELEMENT_NODE:
                $nodesChanged = mapOntoTextNodes($node->childNodes->item($i), $callback);
                break;
            case XML_TEXT_NODE:
                $nodesChanged = $callback($node->childNodes->item($i));
                break;
        }
        if ($nodesChanged !== 0) {
            $n += $nodesChanged;
            $i += $nodesChanged;
        }
    }
}
function foo(DOMText $node) {
    $pattern = "~((?:http|https|ftp)://(?:\S*?\.\S*?))(?=\s|\;|\)|\]|\[|\{|\}|,|\"|'|:|\<|$|\.\s)~i";
    $parts = preg_split($pattern, $node->nodeValue, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    $n = count($parts);
    if ($n > 1) {
        $parentNode = $node->parentNode;
        $doc = $node->ownerDocument;
        for ($i=1; $i<$n; $i+=2) {
            $a = $doc->createElement('a');
            $a->setAttribute('href', $parts[$i]);
            $a->setAttribute('target', '_blank');
            $a->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($parts[$i]));
            $parentNode->insertBefore($doc->createTextNode($parts[$i-1]), $node);
            $parentNode->insertBefore($a, $node);
        }
        $parentNode->insertBefore($doc->createTextNode($parts[$i-1]), $node);
        $parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
    return $n-1;
}

$str = '<div>sometext http://www.somedomain.com/index.html sometext <img src="http//domain.com/image.jpg"> sometext sometext</div>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);
$elems = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body');
mapOntoTextNodes($elems->item(0), 'foo');
```

Here `mapOntoTextNodes` is used to map a given callback function onto every [*DOMText*](http://php.net/domtext) node in a DOM document. You can either pass the whole [*DOMDocument*](http://php.net/domdocument) node or just a specific [*DOMNode*](http://php.net/domnode) (in this case just the `BODY` node).

The function `foo` is then used to find and replace the plain URLs in the *DOMText* node’s content by splitting the content string into *non-URL*‍/‍*URL* parts using [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) while capturing the used delimiter resulting in an array of 1+2·*n* items. Then the *non-URL* parts are replaced by new *DOMText* nodes and the *URL* parts are replaced by new `A` elements that are then inserted before the origin *DOMText* node that is then removed at the end. Since this `mapOntoTextNodes` walks recursively, it suffices to just call that function on a specific *DOMNode*.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i need to to use regex, because its much lighter and faster rater the using several function

Comment: @Andri: But using regular expressions might give an unexpected result since HTML is an irregular language.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the reply, but its still does work. i have fixed using this function:

```
function livelinked ($text){
        preg_match_all("#((http|https|ftp)://(\S*?\.\S*?))(\s|\;|\)|\]|\[|\{|\}|,|\"|'|:|\<|$|\.\s)|^(jpg)#ie", $text, $ccs);
        foreach ($ccs[3] as $cc) {
           if (strpos($cc,"jpg")==false  && strpos($cc,"gif")==false && strpos($cc,"png")==false ) {
              $old[] = "http://".$cc;
              $new[] = '<a href="http://'.$cc.'" target="_blank">'.$cc.'</a>';
           }
        }
        return str_replace($old,$new,$text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to keep using a regex (and in this case, a regex is quite appropriate), you can have the regex match only URLs that "stand alone". Using a [word boundary escape sequence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) (`\b`), you can only have the regex match where `http` is immediately preceded by whitespace or the beginning of the text:

```
preg_replace("#\b((http|https|ftp)://(\S*?\.\S*?))(\s|\;|\)|\]|\[|\{|\}|,|\"|'|:|\<|$|\.\s)#ie", "'<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$1</a>$4'", $text);
            // ^^ thar she blows
```

Thus, `"http://..."` won't match, but `http://` as its own word will.

Comment: It will also not match any URLs at the end of a sentence, e.g. followed by a full stop or those part of a comma separated enumeration and so on. And needless to say, quotes are not even required in HTML attributes.

Comment: The description of word boundaries is incorrect, too.  Used as shown here, the `\b` only asserts that the `http`, `https` or `ftp` is not immediately preceded by a letter, a digit, or an underscore.  It **will** match before the `h` in `"http` or `=http`, so it doesn't prevent matches in attribute values as you seem to be claiming.

Answer (score 0):

DomDocument is more mature and runs much faster, so it's just an alternative if someone wants to use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/):

```
<?php
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = str_get_html('sometext sometext http://www.somedomain.com/index.html sometext sometext
<a href="http://www.somedomain.com/index.html">http://www.somedomain.com/index.html</a>
sometext sometext <img src="http//domain.com/image.jpg"> sometext sometext');

foreach ($html->find('text') as $element)
{
    // you can add any tag into the array to exclude from replace
    if (!in_array($element->parent()->tag, array('a')))
        $element->innertext = preg_replace("#((http|https|ftp)://(\S*?\.\S*?))(\s|\;|\)|\]|\[|\{|\}|,|\"|'|:|\<|$|\.\s)#ie", "'<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$1</a>$4'", $element->innertext);
}

echo $html;
```

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Answer (score 0):

You can try my code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239425/php-reg-ex-for-parsing-a-link/4239671#4239671):

```
echo preg_replace('/<a href="([^"]*)([^<\/]*)<\/a>/i', "$1", 'sometext sometext <img src="http//domain.com/image.jpg"> sometext sometext');
```

If you wanna turn some other tags - that's easy enough:

```
echo preg_replace('/<img src="([^"]*)([^\/><]*)>/i', "$1", 'sometext sometext <img src="http//domain.com/image.jpg"> sometext sometext');
```

Answer (score 0):

match a whitespace (\s) at the start and end of the url string, this will ensure that

```
"http://url.com"
```

is not matched by

```
http://url.com
```

is matched;