# PHP Regular expression to replace link url

Tags: php, regex

I need to add **`href="`** before an **`http://`** if this **`http://`** doesn't follow **`href="`** or **`src="`**

Following code partly works. Partly means it considers **`<a href="`** only but not **`src="`**

```
$str= preg_replace( 
    "/(?<!a href=\")((http|ftp)+(s)?:\/\/[^<>\s]+)/i", 
    "<a href=\"\\0\"> target=\"blank\">\\0</a>", 
    $str
);
```

Thank you guys in advance for your reply.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003031/regex-replacing-text-url-but-exclude-image-url

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=regex+link

Comment: You also do not want to replace the URL if it is part of an anchor element, e.g. `<a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>`

Comment: Or a `link`, or a `meta`, or part of a `script`, etc., etc., etc., rant, rant, rant, conclusion: use a parser.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. These are good thoughts. I will do it when my boss finds he needs it (to let my boss know he needs a programmer....)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege)

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$str= preg_replace( 
    "/(?<!a href=\")(?<!src=\")((http|ftp)+(s)?:\/\/[^<>\s]+)/i", 
    "<a href=\"\\0\" target=\"blank\">\\0</a>", 
    $str
);
```

Comment: Would be lovely if this included any sort of description / comments.  Code-only answers are hard enough, but RegEx is a whole 'nother monster!