# How to stop url spam in php have put url validaiton on msg field but not working

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, spam-prevention, url-validation

unable to stop spam url links in msg field in PHP has put the preg_match() check but it also getting bypassed.

how it is possible here is my code:

```
if($_SESSION['captcha_code']==$_POST['captcha'])
 {
     $regex = "/(http:\/\/|)(www.|)[\d\w-]{2,63}\.[A-Z]{2,4}(\.[A-Z]{2,4}|)/i";  
     if (preg_match($regex,$_POST['message'],$match))
{   
echo '<script>alert("URL links are not allowed, please remove following URL link from the message");window.history.go(-1);</script>'; return;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some spam messages with URL that you failed to block?

Comment: You may use https://pastebin.com if you don't want to spam URL here :-)

Comment: Thi regex will do the job `/((http|ftp)+(s)?:\/\/[^<>\s]+)/i` see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036952/php-regular-expression-to-replace-link-url