# Wrap in <a> tags specific characters in HTML tables with regex & PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a text... and in it I have paragraphs and tables... I need to replace every X (a single Japanese kanji character to be precise... but it could be any character) which is in one of the tables with `<a href="http://example.com/#X">X</a>`, but only those X that are in the tables, not outside of them.

There can be several X in a single table so `preg_replace('#<td>(X)#','replacewith',$source)` wouldn't work as it replaces only one of the X.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify what you're asking (as per my answer).

Comment: "... HTML... regex...". This alarms and concerns me.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$startIndex = strpos($source, '<table');

while ($startIndex !== false) {
    $endIndex = strpos($source, '</table>', $startIndex);

    $excerpt = substr($source, $startIndex, $endIndex - $startIndex);
    $excerpt = preg_replace('/(X|Y|Z)/', '<a href="http://example.com/#$1">$1</a>', $excerpt);
    $source = substr_replace($source, $excerpt, $startIndex, $endIndex - $startIndex);

    if (strlen($source) < $endIndex)
        $startIndex = false;
    else
        $startIndex = strpos($source, '<table', $endIndex);
}
```

**Edit**: fixed, tested, works.

Comment: I have many tables with many characters in them... ex.: XY Z Q <table><tr><td>XY</td><td>XQ</td><td>Z QY</td></tr></table> XY QXZ etc... I need to wrap all X that are inside <table> with the link...

Comment: That's nearly it! It works fine except that it only wraps kanji in the first table... I need to do that for every table in the text. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Philip: Figured out the problem.  Fixed now.

Comment: Well, it doesn't throw the error anymore... but for some reason it started replacing characters even when they are outside of tables.

Comment: Shouldn't $endIndex in substr_replace be a length, and not a position?

Comment: Solved! Please add `- $endIndex` in all `strpos` and `substr_replace` and I'll mark this as accepted answer :)

Comment: or no... if you add it to the last strpos it starts throwing the 30s error again. WTF :/ It works fine if I add it only to the first strpos and the substr_replace. Very strange.

Comment: If you change `$endIndex` to `$endIndex - $startIndex` in `substr` and in `substr_replace`. Because these accept length and not position as an argument.

Comment: Ah.  I had it that way before, but slightly differently; and it was messing up the value of `$startIndex`.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

parsing html with regex is really not pretty.
have a look here how its done and adapt: [How to replace text URLs and exclude URLs in HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003031/how-to-replace-text-urls-and-exclude-urls-in-html-tags/4037753#4037753)