# Regular Expressions, avoiding HTML tags in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex

I have actually seen this question quite a bit here, but none of them are exactly what I want... Lets say I have the following phrase:

```
Line 1 - This is a TEST phrase.
Line 2 - This is a <img src="TEST" /> image.
Line 3 - This is a <a href="somelink/TEST">TEST</a> link.
```

Okay, simple right? I am trying the following code:

```
$linkPin = '#(\b)TEST(\b)(?![^<]*>)#i';
$linkRpl = '$1<a href="newurl">TEST</a>$2';

$html = preg_replace($linkPin, $linkRpl, $html);
```

As you can see, it takes the word TEST, and replaces it with a link to test. The regular expression I am using right now works good to avoid replacing the TEST in line 2, it also avoids replacing the TEST in the href of line 3. However, it still replaces the text encapsulated within the tag on line 3 and I end up with:

```
Line 1 - This is a <a href="newurl">TEST</a> phrase.
Line 2 - This is a <img src="TEST" /> image.
Line 3 - This is a <a href="somelink/TEST"><a href="newurl">TEST</a></a> link.
```

This I do not want as it creates bad code in line 3. I want to not only ignore matches inside of a tag, but also encapsulated by them. (remember to keep note of the /> in line 2)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace text URLs and exclude URLs in HTML tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003031/how-to-replace-text-urls-and-exclude-urls-in-html-tags)

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Sorry, but as I said before, I've already checked most of those. Those questions are not the same as I am asking here. Those are mostly about how to automatically parse links; that is not what I am trying to do here. What I am trying to do here is replace text with a link; the text itself is not the link.

Comment: No, the underlying problem is the same: Separate HTML tag parts from plain text parts and apply a function only on the plain text parts. Identifying URLs in those plain text parts is just one possible form of this function. You can use [the `mapOntoTextNode` function as described in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003031/how-to-replace-text-urls-and-exclude-urls-in-html-tags/4003045#4003045) with any function that accepts a *DOMText* object. The only restriction is that you need to use [DOM](http://php.net/book.dom) operations to modify the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... I think I came up with a better solution...

```
$noMatch = '(</a>|</h\d+>)';

$linkUrl = 'http://www.test.com/test/'.$link['page_slug'];
$linkPin = '#(?!(?:[^<]+>|[^>]+'.$noMatch.'))\b'.preg_quote($link['page_name']).'\b#i';
$linkRpl = '<a href="'.$linkUrl.'">'.$link['page_name'].'</a>';

$page['HTML'] = preg_replace($linkPin, $linkRpl, $page['HTML']);
```

With this code, it won't process any text within `<a>` tags and `<h#>` tags. I figure, any new exclusions I want to add, simply need to be added to $noMatch.

Am I wrong in this method?

Comment: Regular Expressions can get pretty unreadable. That doesn't mean they don't work.

Comment: Not to mention that it can likely be broken pretty badly by malformed XML/HTML.  If this is coming from user input, I wouldn't use regex...

Comment: actually, there is no reason they have to be unreadable when you use the x modifier you can use whitespace and documentation. It's just poor pratice to write them in one line, just like it's poor practice not to use a DOM parser for this kind of work.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I'd do this with DomDocument and Xpath:

```
//First, create a simple html string around the text.
$html = '<html><body><div id="#content">'.$text.'</div></body></html>';

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);

$query = '//*[not(name() = "a") and contains(., "TEST")]';
$nodes = $xpath->query($query);

//Force it to an array to break the reference so iterating works properly
$nodes = iterator_to_array($nodes); 
$replaceNode = function ($node) {
    $text = $node->wholeText;
    $text = str_replace('TEST', '<a href="TEST">TEST</a>', '');
    $fragment = $node->ownerDocument->createDocumentFragment();
    $fragment->appendXML($text);
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($fragment, $node);
}

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    if ($node instanceof DomText) {
        $replaceNode($node, 'TEST');
    } else {
        foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
            if ($child instanceof DomText) {
                $replaceNode($node, 'TEST');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should work for you, since it ignores all text inside of `a` elements, and only replaces the text directly inside of the matching tags.