# Apply wordwrap to html content, excluding html attributes

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, word-wrap

I'm not used to regular expressions so this might seem easy while tricky for me.

Basically, i'm applying wordwrap to content, that contains classic html tags : , ...

```
  $text = wordwrap($text, $cutLength, " ", $wordCut);
  $text = nl2br(bbcode_parser($text));
  return $text;
```

As you can see, my problem is pretty simple : all I want is to apply wordwrap() to my content, excluding what could be in html attributes : href , src ...

Could someone help me out ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: You're going to have to parse the HTML.  Do a search, there are about 1000 posts on here about just that.  Maybe you could use strip_tags then wrap, and combine back with original...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use regex for html parsing of course, but this should separate out
content should you want to. I have limited knowledge of php so this just illustrates procedure.

```
$tags = 
'  <
   (?:
       /?\w+\s*/?
     | \w+\s+ (?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+\s*/?
     | !(?:DOCTYPE.*?|--.*?--)
   )>
';

$scripts =
'   <
   (?:
       (?:script|style) \s*
     | (?:script|style) \s+ (?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+\s*
   )>
   .*?
   </(?:script|style)\s*>
';

$regex = / ($scripts | $tags) | ((?:(?!$tags).)+) /xsg;
```

The replacement string is Group1 catted to the return value of your
word wrap function (which is passed the content, Group2 string)
so something like:  replacement = \1 . textwrap( \2 )
Inside of textwrap you decide what to do with the content.

Tested in Perl (btw its very slow and watered down for clarity):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $tags = 
'  <
   (?:
       /?\w+\s*/?
     | \w+\s+ (?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+\s*/?
     | !(?:DOCTYPE.*?|--.*?--)
   )>
';

my $scripts =
'   <
   (?:
       (?:script|style) \s*
     | (?:script|style) \s+ (?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+\s*
   )>
   .*?
   </(?:script|style)\s*>
';

my $html = join '', <DATA>;

while ( $html =~ / ($scripts | $tags) | ((?:(?!$tags).)+) /xsg ) {
    if (defined $2 && $2 !~ /^\s+$/) {
        print $2,"\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [any DOM parser capable of extracting the text nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662) from the document. Iterate over the text nodes, apply `wordwrap` on them and write them back to their respective text nodes.

The approach is identical to that one given in

- [How to replace text URLs and exclude URLs in HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003031/how-to-replace-text-urls-and-exclude-urls-in-html-tags)

just instead of checking the text content for links, you apply your `wordwrap` on them.

The more general phrasing of your problem would be: "How to (selectively) fetch the text content of a HTML document to apply a function to it"