# php - wordwrap with html

Tags: php, tinymce, word-wrap

The problem is simple:

Using [tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/), I am storing html data into the database. Then at the home page, I am showing 5 latest posts I've inserted into the database. I want to crop each of these posts to the specified length if they exceed it and put a `continue reading` link (can be a soft crop here, doesn't have to be rigid).

It would be easy to crop the string with php's `wordwrap` function but since the string is composed of html I don't wanna ruin the html code by cropping it from a wrong place.

So the question is: Is there an easy way to crop this, (can be a css, javascript solution as well) or do I have a write a long function with lots of checks to implement such a basic feature? I was thinking to use the `DOM` class but before creating function I just wanted to ask you guys.

**EDIT**

Styling is essential to me. So there is no possibility to strip the tags.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682878/apply-wordwrap-to-html-content-excluding-html-attributes

Comment: The page was already opened in the other tab :) Actually I got the DOM idea from that post :) @Arvind

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution could be to strip tags, if the styling of this HTML is not vital, so you can cut wherever you want:
http://php.net/manual/es/function.strip-tags.php

Another solution for CSS3 browsers, would be to use text-overflow, read more about this:
http://davidwalsh.name/css-ellipsis

Comment: Unfortunately the first option is not possible. As for the second option I've already considered that. But still, how can one add continue reading link by using css?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you use jQuery

**the javascript**

```
     $(function () {
        $('p').filter(function () {
           return $(this).height() > 50;
        }).addClass('collapsed').css('position', 'relative').append('<a href="#" class="expand">read more</a>');
        $('.expand').on('click', function(){
           if($(this).parents('.collapsed').length)
              $(this).parents('.collapsed:first').removeClass('collapsed')
           else
              $(this).parents(':first').addClass('collapsed')

        })
     })
```

**the css**

```
.collapsed{overflow: hidden; height: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px; position: relative}
.expand{position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; background: #fff; padding: 0 0 0 15px;}
```

Just a proof of concept. Needs JS optimization

Comment: I've already found such a plugin: http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/. The only problem with jQuery is that it waits till the page loads so the content first loads as it has to, then it gets cropped (even when using overflow: hidden there is a piece of text which appears and renders the display awkward). Although, not the perfect one, if I cannot find a better solution I will accept this answer as correct. Thanks a lot for the suggestion.