# Wrap bold/strong tags around first occurrence of keyword inside content fragment?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, domdocument

I'm looking for the simplest way to wrap bold tags around the first appearance of a predefined keyword phrase, when that phrase does not appear in a heading tag or as an html attribute value. After the first match is found, exits the routine.

For example, if the keyword is "blue widgets", and the content was:

```
blue widgets and accessories for blue widgets can be found here
```

Then after the routine filters the content, it would return:

```
<b>blue widgets</b> and accessories for blue widgets can be found here
```

However, if the first occurrence of the word "blue widgets" were in an attribute or a heading tag, it would skip over those and go to the next one. For example,

```
<img src="foo.png" title="A site about blue widgets" alt="blue-widget" />
<h2>This is a site about blue widgets</h2>
<p>We've got lots of blue widgets and blue widget accessories...
```

In the above content, only the appearance of the keyword in the sentence "We've got lots of **blue widgets** and blue widget accessories"... would be bolded.

Can someone give me an example of how this can be done?

Comment: use `<strong>` instead of `<b>` ;)

Comment: It seems wrong to do this on the HTML... You don't have control of the system that generates the HTML?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace text URLs and exclude URLs in HTML tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003031/how-to-replace-text-urls-and-exclude-urls-in-html-tags) - the approach is the same. Find all text nodes. Iterate over them. Instead of the URL you find your keywords and wrap them into the desired markup.

Comment: @Casper, sure. I'm just using b for simplicity, but you are correct, strong is the more semantically correct way to do it.

Comment: @Pez - its deploying as a plugin for WordPress and installed at the discretion of the site owner for their content.

Comment: @Gordon, there are some good examples at that reference point. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're still thinking about using a regex, check this out:

```
$source = <<<EOS
<img src="foo.png" title="A site about blue widgets" alt="blue-widget" />
<h2>This is a site about blue widgets</h2>
<p>We've got lots of blue widgets and blue widget accessories...';
EOS;

$term = 'blue widgets';

// convert search term to valid regex
$term0 = preg_replace(array('~\A\b~', '~\b\z~', '~\s+~'), 
                      array('\b', '\b', '\s+'),
                      preg_quote(trim($term), '~'));

$regex = <<<EOR
~\A   # anchoring at string start ensures only one match can occur
(?>
   <(h[1-6])[^>]*>.*?</\\1>   # a complete h<n> element
 | </?\w+[^>]*+>              # any other tag
 | (?:(?!<|{$term0}).)*+      # anything else, but stop before '<' or the search term
)*+
\K    # pretend the match really started here; only the next part gets replaced
{$term0}
~isx
EOR;

echo preg_replace($regex, "<strong>$0</strong>", $source);
```

**[run it on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/LRzhT)**

I wasn't even sure it was *possible* to do this with a regex, which is why I went to the trouble of working it out.  Hideous as this solution is, it's about as simple as I could make it.  And to do that I had to ignore many factors that can break it--things like CDATA sections, SGML comments, `<script>` elements, and angle brackets in attribute values, to name a few.  And that's just in **valid** HTML.

Fun as this was, I hope it persuades you once and for all to forget about regexes and use a dedicated tool, as the other responders advised.