# Change specific words into links within HTML using PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, html-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace text URLs and exclude URLs in HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003031/how-to-replace-text-urls-and-exclude-urls-in-html-tags)

Given some HTML markup, I want to add  links around specific words in the text.  But I don't want to affect attributes, or non-visble words.  Nor do I want to end up double linking words (eg. `<a href="#">I went to <a href="#">China</a></a>`.

**Sample**

```
<h2>We are speaking English</h2>
<p>When speaking to somebody you can use our handy <a href="/speaking-guide.html">
    speaking guide</a>.</p>
```

**Ideal result on linkng 'speaking'**

```
<h2>We are <a>speaking</a> English</h2>
<p>When <a>speaking</a> to somebody you can use our handy <a href="/speaking-guide.html">
    speaking guide</a>.</p>
```

Note that the href of the existing link has not been changed, nor has the word speaking within the pre-existing link.

What is the proper way to do this?  If not using regex then with what?

Comment: **The HTML DOM is the right way.** I am just too lazy right now to write the complete code.

Comment: I don't see how the DOM can be useful if he's not using Javascript.

Comment: @Merijn : You can parse HTML DOM with PHP.

Comment: There's Simple HTML Dom - I'm familiar with it but I can't see how to apply it in this context.

Comment: Have you used PHP DomDocument? This is the way to go.

Comment: There is way to many comment flags in this question: don't abuse the system.