# How replace all spaces inside HTML elements with &nbsp; using preg_replace?

Tags: php, html, preg-replace, spaces

I need replace spaces with `&nbsp;` inside HTML elements.
Example:

```
<table atrr="zxzx"><tr>
<td>adfa a   adfadfaf></td><td><br /> dfa  dfa</td>
</tr></table>
```

should become

```
<table atrr="zxzx"><tr>
<td>adfa&nbsp;a&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;adfadfaf></td><td><br />&nbsp;dfa&nbsp;&nbsp;dfa</td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: what is the server side language ? or do you mean javascript ?

Comment: @Krtek - searching for `preg_replace` finds PHP results, so one cane assume this is a PHP question.

Comment: Have you ever thought of using CSS like [`white-space: pre`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege)

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use regex to catch data between tags

```
(?:<\/?\w+)(?:\s+\w+(?:\s*=\s*(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^'\">\s]+)?)+\s*|\s*)\/?>([^<]*)?
```

then replace `' '` with `'&nbsp;'`

also to catch before and after html :

```
^([^<>]*)<?

>([^<>]*)$
```

Edit:
here you go....

```
<?php
$data="dasdad asd a  <table atrr=\"zxzx\"><tr><td>adfa a   adfadfaf></td><td><br /> dfa  dfa</td></tr></table>  asdasd s ";
$exp="/((?:<\\/?\\w+)(?:\\s+\\w+(?:\\s*=\\s*(?:\\\".*?\\\"|'.*?'|[^'\\\">\\s]+)?)+\\s*|\\s*)\\/?>)([^<]*)?/";

$ex1="/^([^<>]*)(<?)/i";
$ex2="/(>)([^<>]*)$/i";

$data = preg_replace_callback($exp, function ($matches) {
    return $matches[1] . str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $matches[2]);
}, $data);
$data = preg_replace_callback($ex1, function ($matches) {
    return str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $matches[1]) . $matches[2];
}, $data);
$data = preg_replace_callback($ex2, function ($matches) {
    return $matches[1] . str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $matches[2]);
}, $data);

echo $data;
?>
```

it works... slightly modified but it would work without modifications (but i dont think youd understand the code ;) )

Comment: how is it not working for you ? -.-'''' what function do you use ?

Comment: i provided working php code. tell me if you have further problems

Comment: n00b32 i run you code. Result - changed data outside html tags. Table til content spaces. I use php 5.3.5

Comment: if you remove the second and third line begginin with `'$data ='` the code does exactly what you posted in your question... i use php 5.2.6-1+lenny9 so i think its consistent with your version

Comment: It's very strange but $exp not working, $ex1 and $ex2 is ok. preg_match return 0.

Comment: ks****:~# php lol.php
`dasdad&nbsp;asd&nbsp;a&nbsp;&nbsp;<table atrr="zxzx"><tr><td>adfa&nbsp;a&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;adfadfaf></td><td><br />&nbsp;dfa&nbsp;&nbsp;dfa</td></tr></table>&nbsp;&nbsp;asdasd&nbsp;s&nbsp;`

Comment: if the code with no modifications doesnt work i would have to guess something is wrong with your editor/configuration/server ...

Comment: put `((?:<\/?\w+)(?:\s+\w+(?:\s*=\s*(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^'\">\s]+)?)+\s*|\s*)\/?>)([^<]*)?` as regex and `<table atrr="zxzx"><tr>
<td>adfa a   adfadfaf></td><td><br /> dfa  dfa</td>
</tr></table>` as teststring1 ... it works...

Comment: Yes its work. But on my php 5.3.5(freebsd and windows) still not work. Thanks  n00b32.

Comment: <table atrr="zxzx"><tr><td>adfa a adfadfaf></td><td><br /> dfa dfa</td> </tr></table>

Comment: After ading /x. Result: `<table atrr="zxzx"><tr><td>adfa a adfadfaf></td><td><br />&nbsp;dfa&nbsp;dfa</td> </tr></table>`

Comment: then im sorry i dont know why it doesnt work on your server... the problem AFAIK doesnt lay in my code, so youre on your own. the regex should work so try experimenting with it

Answer (score 8):

If you're working with php, you can do

```
$content = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $content);
```

Comment: all spaces within attributes of html tags will be replaced as well

Answer (score 3):

Since tokenizing HTML with regular expressions can be quite complicated (especially when allowing SGML quirks), you should use an HTML DOM parser like the one of [PHP’s DOM library](http://php.net/book.dom). Then you can query the DOM, get all text nodes and apply your replacement function on it:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);
$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
mapOntoTextNodes($body, function(DOMText $node) { $node->nodeValue = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $node->nodeValue); });
```

The [`mapOntoTextNodes` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003031/how-to-replace-text-urls-and-exclude-urls-in-html-tags/4003045#4003045) is a custom function I had defined in [*How to replace text URLs and exclude URLs in HTML tags?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003031/how-to-replace-text-urls-and-exclude-urls-in-html-tags)

Comment: isint this a bit of an overkill ? and if we are to overkill it we need to detect style/script etc etc tags...

Comment: I don't need to parse all html file. I need parse some parts like i posted in question.