# Convert all spaces to &nbsp; between PRE tags in HTML string data

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Similar to this question [How replace all spaces inside HTML elements with &nbsp; using preg_replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210287/how-replace-all-spaces-inside-html-elements-with-nbsp-using-preg-replace)

Except I need to do this from phpmyadmin (SQL query) for all PRE elements stored in the SQL table "jos_picmicro_content" in the field "fulltext". All other html elements are to be left untouched.

How would I go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you have to do it in PHPMyAdmin. You could just write a PHP script with a query to get the data, than do a `for` which replaces the stuff in them one by one, and an other query that updates your table with the new data. Run the scipt once, you can delete it afterwards. That is how I'd do it.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. I have one more question to ask on stack and then will start on this! Cheers.

Comment: ...And make sure your code that inserts to that table inserts properly escaped data in the future.