# How can spaces be converted to &nbsp without breaking HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

I've inherited some pretty complex code for a web forum, and one of the features I'm trying to implement is the ability for spaces to not be truncated into only one. This is mainly because our users often want to include ASCII art, tables etc in their posts.

I first did this using a simple search and replace in javascript, which had the side effect of breaking HTML tags (eg `<a href=....>` became `<a&nbsp;href=.....>`).

I then tried doing this on server side, when the strings are retrieved, by having spaces converted before links and code people insert is converted to HTML. This works to a degree but it causes some issues with other parts of the code, for example where a message is truncated to appear on the home page, it might leave some of the space code, such as

> Here is a message&nb

I think there may be a way to just alter the original javascript to achieve this - it just needs to only match spaces that are not inside a HTML tag.

The script I was using originally was `message = message.replace(/\s/g, "&nbsp;")`.

Thanks for any help you can provide with this.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210287/how-replace-all-spaces-inside-html-elements-with-nbsp-using-preg-replace for a PHP solution, which contains the relevant regex pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `pre` element to include preformatted text, which renders spaces as-is. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/the-pre-element.html

Those docs specifically say one of the best uses of the `pre` element is "Displaying ASCII art".

Example: http://jsbin.com/owuruz/edit#preview

```
<pre>
         /\_/\
    ____/ o o \
  /~____  =ø= /
 (______)__m_m)
</pre>
```

In your case, just put your `message` inside a `pre` tag.

Comment: +1 for good answer and cute kitty! ;-) But yes, use pre tags rather than messing with the whitespace.

Comment: I have to admit the kitty is not mine. It is in the public domain, but the author is someone else. Here's where I got it: http://www.chris.com/ascii/index.php?art=animals/cats

Comment: Thanks very much for that - I feel very silly for not knowing about the pre tag! I did it slightly differently by setting the body of the message to have the 'white-space:pre' CSS property but it has the same effect. MUCH easier than messing about with regular expressions!

Comment: The `pre` element, as well as its CSS counterpart, has several effects, including special treatment of spaces (which is partly similar, but not identical with, the effect of changing spaces to no-break spaces). In particular, it prescribes that line breaks appear in display exactly as in HTML source. So while `pre` may well be a good answer to many questions (possibly including the question that *should* have been asked in this case), it does not address the question of changing spaces to no-break spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you need to process text content of elements, not all of the HTML document content. Moreover, you need to exclude `style` and `script` element content. As you can limit yourself to things inside the `body` element, you could use a recursive function like following, calling it with `process(document.body)` to apply it to the entire document (but you probably want to apply it to a specific element only):

```
function process(element) { 
  var children = element.childNodes; 
  for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) { 
    var child = children[i]; 
    if(child.nodeType === 3) { 
      if(child.data) { 
        child.data = child.data.replace(/[ ]/g, "\xa0"); 
      } 
    } else if(child.tagName != "SCRIPT") { 
      process(child); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

(No reason to use the entity reference `&nbsp;` here; you can use the no-break space character U+00A0 itself, referring to it as `"\xa0"` in JavaScript.)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use <pre> tags to wrap your users posts so that their ASCII art is preserved.  But why not use Markdown (like Stackoverflow does).  There's a couple of different ports of Markdown to Javascript:

- [Showdown](http://www.showdown.im/)
- [WMD](http://code.google.com/p/wmd/)
- [uedit](https://github.com/amir-hadzic/uedit)