# PHP: Converting text links to anchor tags

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I am pulling in RSS feeds and using DOMXPath to convert all existing anchor tags to custom tags that look like this for various reasons:

```
[webserviceLink]{$url}[/webserviceLink][webserviceLinkName]{$text}[/webserviceLinkName]
```

This works great, but I'd also like to covert all non-html text links to this same format, but am having some issues.

Here's my code for converting the text links:

```
$pattern = '(?xi)(?<![">])\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))';

$desc = preg_replace_callback("#$pattern#i", function($matches)
{
  $input = $matches[0];
  $url = preg_match('!^https?://!i', $input) ? $input : "http://$input";

  if (strlen($input) > 20 && !strpos($input, " "))
    $input = substr($input, 0, 18)."... ";

  return "[webserviceLink]{$url}[/webserviceLink][webserviceLinkName]{$input}[/webserviceLinkName]";
}, $desc);
```

I'm not sure how to do the negative callback in this regex to check that the link I am converting is not in an existing html tag, like an img, or in my custom link tags above.

Comment: Could you provide an exemple of input//output?

Comment: well, getting your own custom link tags to pass is easy enough as you can put a comment on the end of the line and check for that in your script.

Existing tags could be checked against a list of them i guess, though IE and Chrome custom tags might make that a bitch to error check.

safer to grep for all of the tags you do want to edit, run your code against them, then replace the lines.

Comment: Please see: [How to replace text URLs and exclude URLs in HTML tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4003031/2261774)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use xpath to get this working.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($desc, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xp->query('//text()[not(ancestor::a)]') as $node)
     {
        $pattern = '((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))';

        $replaced = preg_replace_callback("#$pattern#i", function($matches)
        {
          $input = $matches[0];
          $url = preg_match('!^https?://!i', $input) ? $input : "http://$input";

          if (strlen($input) > 20 && !strpos($input, " "))
            $input = substr($input, 0, 18)."... ";

          return "<a href=\"{$url}\">{$input}</a>";
        }, $node->wholeText);

          $newNode  = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
          $newNode->appendXML($replaced);
          $node->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $node);
     }
```