# auto detect link of a string and add <a> tag, but not replace <img>,<iframe>

Tags: php, replace

I have written the following code to automatically detect link text in a string and add an `<a>` tag:

```
$content= preg_replace_callback(
    '#(?:https?://\S+)|(?:www.\S+)|(?:\S+\.\S+)#',
    function($arr) {
        if(strpos($arr[0], 'http://') !== 0) {
            $arr[0] = 'http://' . $arr[0];
        }
        $url = parse_url($arr[0]);
        //links
        return sprintf('<a href="%1$s">%1$s</a>', $arr[0]);
    }, $content);
```

This works, but it creates a problem if there is an image or an iframe:

```
<img <a href="http://src="http://i.imgur.com/nXJ06jx.jpg"">
```

How do I make sure that it does not replace links in `<img>` or `<iframe>` tags?

Comment: Simple. Don't use regexes blindly. Use DOM to get **TEXT NODES**  and then scan each of those for links. any "url" in a text node by definition won't be in an `<a>` tag set

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003031/how-to-replace-text-urls-and-exclude-urls-in-html-tags